# Visual Studio is Generating a strange text in my code

Tags: visual-studio, designer, build-error

in my form, when I build it every once in a while I get this error:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRjJk.jpg)

When I click on the error, my designer page opens up and I find this strange giberish text in it:
[Designer Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFwW9.jpg)

I delete the weird string and I make it's value an empty one --> 
SelectedPath = "";

But, again after a couple of builds I get the same error again and that weird text pops up again. I also tried setting it's value to null, but the problem remains.

Can someone please help me understand what studio is doing when I build my project!!! ..

Please note, in my project there are multiple forms, and I only get that error when I'm working on that specific form, when it is not open in my solution, everything runs smoothly.

Comment: i believe this is a glitch with VS, had you try restarting it?

Comment: it looks like a file encoding issue, but not sure how that would be caused at build time...

Comment: @Dr.Stitch Yes I have, this problem appears on any computer I run it on.

Comment: @JanR got any advice on where to dig, if it is indeed an encoding problem?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @AdrianHHH I didn't post pictures because I was too lazy to write man, i posted it them because I thought it would make my case clearer, given that it's something rarely encountered!
However, I will keep what you said in mind next time I post a question, I would hate to think that someone else is facing the same problem and is unable to find references to it while searching.

Comment: You wrote *"I didn't post pictures because I was too lazy to write man"* yet you expect many people to try and help you. Words fail me.